# How can i open an uknown number of images using a pop-up like mechanism in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am a beginner when it comes to creating websites and i have a big problem.
 
I have created a super basic site where a person can login and upload images. Users or guests can search all the images using a filter.
 
What i want to achieve is after a person uses a filter to see the images i want for him to be able to click on any image and show him the image in full scale in a pop-up like window.
 
I have tried the modal image code from w3schools but it only works for the first image shown.
All images are stored in a sql table.
Here is the webpage where it currently just shows the images

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search photo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
            echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['username'];
        }
    ?>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="home.php">Home</a></td>
            <td><a href="addphoto.php">Add new photo</a></td>
            <td><a href="searchphoto.php">Search photo</a></td>
            <td><a href="top5.php">Top 5</a></td>
            <td><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></td>
            <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
                    echo "<td><a href='logout_p.php'>Logout</a></td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td><a href='registration.php'>Register</a></td>";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <form method="post" action="searchphoto.php">
        Select image filter: 
        <select name="s_filter" required>
            <option selected value="all">All
            <option value="face">Faces
            <option value="place">Places
            <option value="car">Cars
            <option value="other">Other
            <option value="bestvote">Best average vote
            <option value="worstvote">Worst average vote
            <option value="text">Text
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Search">
        <br>
        Fill this parameter if you chose Text: <input type="text" name="filter_text">
        <br>
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['search_submit'])){
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","site");
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Fatal error";
            die;
        }

        $filter = $_POST['s_filter'];
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images");
        if($filter == "all"){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "face"){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category='$filter'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "car"){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category='$filter'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "place"){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category='$filter'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "other"){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category='$filter'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "bestvote"){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY avg_vote DESC");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "worstvote"){
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY avg_vote");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }else if($filter == "text"){
            $filter = $_POST['filter_text'];
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE INSTR(description, '{$filter}')");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $image = $row['img'];
                $image_src = "".$image;
    ?>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <img id='myImg' src='<?php echo "".$image_src;?>' alt='Not found' height="300" width="300">
            </div>
            <div style="float: leftt">
            <table border="5" width="300" height="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo "".$image;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Uploader: <?php echo "".$row['up_username'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category: <?php echo "".$row['category'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <?php echo "".$row['description'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average score: <?php echo "".$row['avg_vote'];?>/5</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Votes: <?php echo "".$row['num_votes'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br>
    <?php
                if($_SESSION['username']!=NULL){
    ?>
                    <form method='post' action='vote_p.php'>
                    Give your vote: 
                    <select name='usr_vote'>
                          <option selected value='5'>5
                          <option value='4'>4
                          <option value='3'>3
                          <option value='2'>2
                          <option value='1'>1";
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vote_name' value='<?php echo "".$image;?>'>
                    <input type='submit' name='vote_button' value='vote'>
                    </form><br>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>";
                }           
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Forgive me if the code above is confusing but i just started creating websites.

Comment: Put your image into `<a>` ?

Comment: But wouldnt that open the image in a new webpage? I actually want to stay in the same page like when you open an image in facebook

Comment: You can make a `<a>` tag not to open a new window/browser tab and add some js to put that image into some kind of alert window

Comment: Can you help me write the code, or can you give me a link were i can actually see how that could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in the Image Modal from w3schools here is the code hope you can change it accordingly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img class="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="callfunction(this)">
<img class="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="callfunction(this)">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
//var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
function callfunction(e){
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = e.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = e.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```